# get 3 (max) digit integer from txt file

Tags: c, file

First of all I am new to files in c, so it may be a simple question,
                however I still didn't find a solution:

let's say that's the content of my file:

*99*

*blah blah*

*...*

*...*

---

I want to scan only the number from the beginning (it is always in a separate line)

My question is how to make it take the number (`99`) as one number and stop scanning.

```
    int main(){

        FILE* fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
        int integer;
        ...

        fclose(fp);

        printf("%d", integer);
    }
```

output for the file example:

`99`

-**the nuber can be between 1 and 100**-

Comment: Do you know how to get a single number from a user writing at a console (using e.g. `scanf`)? Then you could just use the same method here (but use `fscanf` instead).

Comment: you mean- `fscanf(fp, "%d", &index)`? but if the next line also begins with an integer, it wouldn't take it? the "\n" between the lines breaks it?

Comment: The `%d` format will read digit characters and parse into an integer. When it reads a non-digit character (like for example a newline) then it will stop. Just like `scanf("%d", &index)` will stop reading at the newline added by the `Enter` key.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to scan only the number from the beginning (**it is always in a separate line**).

That's a good hint, suggesting a line by line parsing of the input. You can use a combination of `fgets`<sup>(1)</sup> and `sscan`<sup>(2)</sup> to read that number.

`fgets` will read up to a certain number of character from a stream and store those character into a buffer. If it finds a newline, it stops reading, store the newline into the buffer followed by the null-terminator. Otherwise it only adds the terminator. If it fails, it returs a NULL pointer.

`sscanf` works basically like `scanf` or `fscanf`, but it reads from a character array, not from a stream.

It's also better to always check the return value of those library function.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int main(void)
{
    char const *file_name = "data.txt"; 
    FILE *in_file = fopen(file_name, "r"); 
    if (!in_file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while reading \"%s\": %s", file_name, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    int number = 0;
    while( fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, in_file) ) {
        if ( sscanf(buffer, "%d", &number) == 1 ) {
            if ( 0 < number  &&  number < 100 ) {
                printf("%d", number);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(in_file);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WlDZjMSLtJlELhla).

Some references of the functions used in the previous snippet

1) `fgets`: [man-pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html) or [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

2) `sscanf`: [man-pages](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) or [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use scanf? (fscanf to be more precise):

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument
>   list successfully filled.

(source: [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/#return))
So just check how many values did you read, if 0 that means it's not a number so you can just skip that string, for that you can use "%*" prefix to ignore the data.
You also said:

> I want to scan only the number from the beginning (it is always in a
>   separate line)

so after you read the number just skip the whole line with "%*[^\n]" (reads
data until a new line symbol is encountered)

```
int num;
int scanReturn;

FILE* f = fopen("file.txt", "r");

...

do {
    scanReturn = fscanf(f, "%d", &num);

    if(scanReturn == 0)
    {
        scanReturn = fscanf(f, "%*s");
    }
    else if(scanReturn != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%*[^\n]");
        printf("%d, ", num);
    }

} while(scanReturn != EOF);

fclose(f);
```